# npm install ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am the npm install -g ionic write code the nodejs console and this error how can I fix . I am one week the this problem and every solution try .
nodejs -v 6.4
npm 3.10.6
cordova 6.3
1) Problem ionic version

```
    C:\Users\jhon>ionic --version
    Caught exception:
     Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/assign'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xmlbuilder\lib\index.js:5:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\xmlbuilder\lib\index.js:14:4)
        at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

2) problem  npm install -g ionic 
**

```
C:\Users\jhon>npm install -g ionic
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.1.9: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.1.0: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)
npm WARN In ionic@2.0.0 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.0.0 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.0.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jhon\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! path C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-6308e9d7
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-6308e9d7' -> 'C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-6308e9d7' -> 'C:\Users\jhon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jhon\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

**

Comment: are  you running behind a proxy

Comment: thanks how can I stop proxy?

Comment: Did u try this? Is it working or what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

**Installing ionic when your running behind a proxy**

Uninstall Node.js if your facing a lot of errors.(optional)

> **Install Nodejs(mandatory)**
>
> **Install Python(mandatory)**
>
> **During installation ensure that environmental variable for python is checked**

**Step 1:** 
start->cmd->(right click ) run as administrator

**Step 2:** 
type the following command **cd** to work as a root user

**Step 3:** 
Setting up windows proxy as below(use your organisation proxies)

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
set https_proxy=https://proxy.organisation.com:8000
```

**Step 4:**
Setting up npm proxy as below(use your organisation proxies)

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.organisation.com:8000
```

**Step 5:**
**Dont navigate to the user folder(From the root folder) execute the following command**

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

which will install both ionic and cordova.

**Possible Errors:**

- Python not found.
- Windows_NT -> reason is your not an administrator.
- ECONNREFUSED -> your connection is not going through proxy check for your proxy in npm using 
  `npm config list` command.