# How to configure angular 2/4 using current user profile (guest or privilege access role) locally

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Issues to install ng command. I am trying to install for completely offline admin access privilege environment.

I have configured angularjs 1.5 environment using current user profile and working fine. I don't have admin right. I need to use proxy as well to serve npm. I am using gulp for angular project 1.x. I have setup environment variable for current user.

I am trying to install @angular/cli. It is not working. 
I am using node version: 7.0.0 and npm version: 3.6.2

I think python is okay.

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx>python
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (
AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

You can see the image, Node was installed inside: C:\Node.js using msiexec /a node-v7.0.0-x64.msi /qb TARGETDIR="C:\Node.js". I also tried by changing it to C:\Users\xxxx\Node.js along with environment variable and removed C:\Node.js. It still doesn't work.

[Here is error message. There is nothing in .log. Left is for npm install @angular/cli and right is for npm install package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kiUO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kiUO.png)

Here is package.json

```js
   

 "name": "user-ui",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --host 'abc.com' --port 4200",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~7.0.0",
        "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
        "tslint": "~5.3.2",
        "typescript": "~2.3.3"
      }
    }
```

Comment: what is that you are looking for?

Comment: Need to configure Angular 4 project for guest or admin access privilege account for offline. One time I can use proxy for npm. npm install -g can't be used. Windows environment variable can't be used. Only can use temp current environment variable.

Comment: Follow this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090625/npm-install-err-code-enoent/39091043#39091043)

Comment: I have already installed npm and configured proxy server. How to install ng command and use it?

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: Thank you for your support. I couldn't do that. I am in problem because of security. Even I don't have github access or I couldn't connect outside network, you can guess now. I am using Angular 4 to develop another project in my home machine. It's easy having admin right. Could you tell me how to install @angular/cli, not globally and use ng command if you know? if you see the above package then it uses ng coomand. I only need to use it from a directory having access. I will try in this weekend in my local machine setting limited access account. Let's hope I can get any solution.

Comment: Install CLi in the specific folder under your project. In the environment variable set path for the cli which might be as `...\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin` try `ng` commands it must work